# Clang and the binary fold expressions — The curse of the empty parameter pack

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-bug, c++17, fold-expression

Specifically Clang 3.6.0, the one currently hosted by Coliru.

All these snippets are called from :

```
int main() {
    foo();
    std::cout << "\n----\n";
    foo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

The following code :

```
template <class... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    std::cout << ... << args;
}
```

Triggers the following compilation error :

```
main.cpp:7:17: error: expected ';' after expression
    std::cout << ... << args;
                ^
                ;
main.cpp:7:15: error: expected expression
    std::cout << ... << args;
              ^
```

So I tried putting parentheses around the expression :

```
(std::cout << ... << args);
```

It works, but triggers a warning :

```
main.cpp:7:6: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    (std::cout << ... << args);
     ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:11:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'foo<>' requested here
    foo();
    ^
```

So I tried to discard the value of the expression with a function-style cast to `void` :

```
void(std::cout << ... << args);
```

But :

```
main.cpp:7:20: error: expected ')'
    void(std::cout << ... << args);
                   ^
main.cpp:7:9: note: to match this '('
    void(std::cout << ... << args);
        ^
```

I tried a `static_cast` too, for the same result.

So I tried with a C-cast instead  :

```
(void)(std::cout << ... << args);
```

But then :

```
main.cpp:6:18: warning: unused parameter 'args' [-Wunused-parameter]
void foo(Args... args) {
                 ^
```

... and my output is only `----` : `foo(1, 2, 3);` doesn't output anymore !

Is Clang cursed by an evil force from future standards, does it have a bug, or is the problem sitting on my chair right now ?

Comment: I cannot get this to compile in any compiler.  tried MSVC2015 and http://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: `static_cast<void>((std::cout << ... << args));` seems to work (that is, double parens), and my guess is that clang is correct, since a fold expression requires its own pair of parentesis

Comment: I had the same setup with cin. If I remember the problem is that somehow it tries to expand `(cin << (1 << 2))` instead of `((cin >> 1)>> 2)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need an extra set of parentheses when casting to `void` using the functional notation cast, otherwise the parentheses are considered part of the cast expression instead of the fold expression. The [fold expression syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) itself requires a set of parentheses.

All of the following work without producing any warnings:

```
void((std::cout << ... << args));
(void)((std::cout << ... << args));
```

Or just call some `ostream` member function to avoid the unused result warning

```
(std::cout << ... << args).flush();
```

---

As T.C. mentions in the comments below, the behavior with `(void)(std::cout << ... << args);` seems like a clang bug. The syntax for a cast notation is specified in *5.4 [expr.cast]*

> *cast-expression*:
>     *unary-expression*
>     *( type-id ) cast-expression*

Since parentheses are not required as part of the cast expression, that usage shouldn't be producing warnings, and more importantly, it should result in printing the arguments.

Comment: I don't see why `(void)(std::cout << ... << args);` doesn't work, though. That part looks like a bug to me.

Comment: So the answer is "all three" then. Thank you very much, Praetorian for the answer and T.C. for the bug report :)

Answer (score 3):

I decided to take a better look at this bug in the Clang source. Here's the offending section of code. This case happens when it's just finished parsing `(<type>)` and is now parsing a following parenthesized expression:

```
} else if (isTypeCast) {
  // Parse the expression-list.
  InMessageExpressionRAIIObject InMessage(*this, false);

  ExprVector ArgExprs;
  CommaLocsTy CommaLocs;

  if (!ParseSimpleExpressionList(ArgExprs, CommaLocs)) {
    // FIXME: If we ever support comma expressions as operands to
    // fold-expressions, we'll need to allow multiple ArgExprs here.
    if (ArgExprs.size() == 1 && isFoldOperator(Tok.getKind()) &&
        NextToken().is(tok::ellipsis))
    return ParseFoldExpression(Result, T);

    ExprType = SimpleExpr;
    Result = Actions.ActOnParenListExpr(OpenLoc, Tok.getLocation(),
                                        ArgExprs);
  }
}

// The beginning of ParseFoldExpression(LHS, T):
if (LHS.isInvalid()) {
  T.skipToEnd();
  return true;
}
```

The specific part of the code responsible for this bug is here:

```
return ParseFoldExpression(Result, T);
```

It turns out that `Result` is never set apart from its initial `true` value. I believe it should be set to `ArgExprs.front()`, which now holds `std::cout`.

Now you'll notice the FIXME as well. While unrelated to this issue in particular, it might be worth fixing alongside this.

Being my first Clang fix, I still have several things to do before submitting a change (for reference, Clang 4.0 is currently in development). I would be more than happy for this to be fixed at all, whether it's by me or someone else. At the very least, my findings are documented somewhere for now.

Answer (score 2):

A fold expression, from [expr.prim.fold] is:

> A fold expression performs a fold of a template parameter pack (14.5.3) over a binary operator.
>       *fold-expression*:
>           ( *cast-expression* *fold-operator* ... )
>           ( ... *fold-operator* *cast-expression* )
>           ( *cast-expression* *fold-operator* ... *fold-operator* *cast-expression* )

Note that in all cases, the parentheses are part of the grammar. So your initial example is syntactically incorrect, and must be:

```
template <class... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```

That will then give you a warning in the case of an empty pack, since the binary fold reduces to just `std::cout;` To get rid of that warning, you can go the usual route of casting to `void` - just that the inner set of parentheses are part of the grammar so you need *two*:

```
void((std::cout << ... << args));
```

Or you could just throw in an extra `endl` or the like:

```
(std::cout << ... << args) << std::endl;
```

Or return the result:

```
template <class... Args>
std::ostream& foo(Args... args) {
    return (std::cout << ... << args);
}
```