# int a[] { (functioncall(a1, a2), 0)...}; (void(a)); What does this syntax do/mean?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, list-initialization

I came across this post [variadic template function to concatenate std::vector containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439221/variadic-template-function-to-concatenate-stdvector-containers) suggesting the use of the following syntax:

```
template<typename T>
void append_to_vector(std::vector<T>& v1, const std::vector<T>& v2) {
  std::cout << v2[0] << std::endl;
  for (auto& e : v2) v1.push_back(e);
}


template<typename T, typename... A>
std::vector<T> concat_version3(std::vector<T> v1, const A&... vr) {
    int unpack[] { (append_to_vector(v1, vr), 1)... };
    (void(unpack));
    return v1;
}
```

I started playing around with it to understand how it worked, since I haven't seen this:

```
int unpack[] { (append_to_vector(v1, vr), 0)... };
(void(unpack));
```

Seems like this is some kind of dynamically generated initialization list that also has side effects? I'm also puzzled by the fact that the `0` above doesn't matter. I substituted, -1 and 5, and each of these values worked just fine too.

So can someone tell me the name of this technique/syntax and what exactly is happening in the two lines above? I'd really appreciate any pointers and apologize if I missed the relevant SO posts.

Comment: This technique achieves the purpose of calling the function `append_to_vector(v1, X)` once for each of the variadic arguments given, with `X` replaced by each element in turn. I call it the "dummy array comma operator hack", don't know if it has an official name :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int unpack[] { (append_to_vector(v1, vr), 1)... };
//        ^^ |                          |   ||| |    array of ints
//           ^                          |    |  ^    array initializer
//                                      ^    |       comma operator
//                                          ^^^      pack expansion
```

This is creating an array of `int`s containing as many elements as the size of the parameter pack `vr`. Each element in the array is `1`, which is what the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) returns after evaluating both arguments. The final ellipsis indicates [pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion) of the parameter pack `vr` is being done.

So if you were to call your function as `concat_version3(v1, v2, v3)` where all arguments are `vector`s, then the above expression would result in

```
int unpack[]{ (append_to_vector(v1, v2), 1), (append_to_vector(v1, v3), 1) };
```

The nice thing about evaluating expressions within a *braced-init-list* is that the order of evaluation is fixed and happens left to right.

*§8.5.4/4 [dcl.init.list]*

> Within the *initializer-list* of a *braced-init-list*, the *initializer-clauses*, including any that result from pack expansions (14.5.3), are **evaluated in the order in which they appear**.

So you're guaranteed that `v2` gets appended to `v1` before `v3`, which is what you want.

---

```
(void(unpack));
```

This is just a way to avoid unused variable warnings from the compiler.

---

Now, I would write your `unpack` initialization a bit differently.

```
int unpack[] { 1, (append_to_vector(v1, vr), 1)... };
//             ^^
```

In the original, if you called the function as `concat_version3(v1)`, i.e. with an empty parameter pack, the code wouldn't compile because you'd be attempting to create a zero sized array, adding the extra element fixes that problem.

Furthermore, if you were using the above expression in more generic code where you didn't know what the return type of `append_to_vector` was, then you'd also need to guard against the possibility of it returning a type that overloads the comma operator. In that case you'd write

```
int unpack[] { 1, (append_to_vector(v1, vr), void(), 1)... };
```

By adding the `void()` expression in between you ensure that no overloaded comma operator is selected, and the built-in one is always called.

---

Finally, if you have a compiler that understands [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), you can do away with the whole array trick and simply write

```
template<typename T, typename... A>
std::vector<T> concat_version3(std::vector<T> v1, const A&... vr)
{
    (void)(((append_to_vector(v1, vr), void()), ...));
    return v1;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d84fc317eda9925)

Note: the extra parentheses after the `void` cast are required due to a [clang bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972828/241631).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very thorough answer. Much obliged.

Comment: The fold expression case could use a `void` cast too (to protect against overloaded commas).

Comment: @T.C. Thank you, didn't consider that possibility, somehow fold expressions seemed too cool to be susceptible to such pitfalls :) Fixed now.

Comment: On another thread someone asked me why this wasn't supported: `append_to_vector(v1, vr)...;` with the same effect and discarding the return values, and I didn't have an answer

Comment: @M.M My guess is allowing the ellipsis to be applied to something other than a parameter pack for expansion, without an intervening operator, would cause ambiguities in the grammar. I've always assumed fold expressions require parentheses around them for similar reasons.