# Compile time error if brace-closed list is the wrong size for class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, list-initialization

I'm trying to write a class based around mathematical vectors:

```
template <unsigned N> class Vector{
public:
    Vector() = default;
    Vector(std::initializer_list<double> li) { *this = li;}
    Vector& operator=(std::initializer_list<double>);

private:
    std::array<double, N> x = {}
}

template <unsigned N> inline Vector<N>& Vector<N>::operator=(std::initializer_list<double> li){
     if(N != li.size()) throw std::length_error("Attempt to initialise Vector with an initializer_list of different size.");
     std::copy(li.begin(), li.end(), x.begin());
     return *this;
}
```

I want to be able to write code like this;

```
Vector<3> a = {1,2,3};
a = {3,5,1};
```

It would be natural for a user to expect to write code like that, right? However I want *compile*-time errors to occur if I use the wrong-sized initializer list, much like `std::array` does.

```
 std::array<double, 3> a = {2,4,2,4} //compile time error
 Vector<3> a = {3,5,1,5} //run-time error as of right now
```

My first idea was to use `std::array` as the constructor/operator parameter so implicit conversions would occur and then the constructor would hijack, from `std::array`, the compile time errors. Except of course I could only write code like this:

```
Vector<3> a({2,3,2}); //fine
Vector<3> b = {2,4,2}; //error, requires two user-defined conversions (list -> array<double,3> -> Vector<3>)
```

I thought maybe to use a Variadic member template:

```
template <typename... Args> Vector(Args... li): x({li...}){
    static_assert(sizeof...(li) == N);
}
```

It has to be `typename...` rather than `double...` because nontype parameters must be integral types. But then I run in to a narrowing conversion error

```
Vector<2> a = {3,2} //error: narrowing conversion of 'li#0' from 'int' to 'double' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]|
 //error: narrowing conversion of 'li#1' from 'int' to 'double' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]|
```

Presumably for violating [8.5.4]/7

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a **constant expression** and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or

The parameters from expanding `li...` aren't constant expressions and hence produce the narrowing conversion error. As far as I'm aware it wouldn't even be possible to make function parameters as constant expressions (nor would it make much sense?). So I'm not sure how to carry on down that route. Obviously `Vector<2> a = {2.,3.}` works fine but this puts a burden on the user to remember only to supply floating-point literals.

Comment: do you want to allow shorter lists, e.g. `Vector<3> a = { 1,2 };` ?

Comment: afaik initializer list can normally only be used for initialization not for assignment, thus I would anser (the only question I could find) with no.

Comment: @M.M I wasn't too sure. Would a user expect to be able to do that like they can with built in arrays or containers? I personally would like to force the list to be the exact same size.

Comment: It seems like you've really got 2 questions, (1) how to enforce length for initialization, (2) how to enforce length for assignment operator. Is that right?

Comment: @M.M Yeah, but maybe the solution to one hints at the solution for the other.

Comment: Inside your variadic template thingy... Any reason this won't work: `static_assert(sizeof...(args) - 1 < Size, "Boom");`

Comment: Taking your quote to the letter, the "source" in your failing example _is_ a constant expression... There's just an extra level of indirection...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your constructor a variadic template so that any condition can be used:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class vector
{
public:
    vector(T&& value)
    : data{static_cast<T>(value)}
    {}
    template<typename U>
    vector(const vector<U,N>& v)
    {
      std::copy(begin(v.data), end(v.data),
                begin(data));
    }
    template<typename U>
    vector(const vector<U,N>& v)
    {
        std::copy(begin(v.data), end(v.data),
                  begin(data));
    }
    template<typename... U,
             typename = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(U)-1>::type>
    vector(U&&... values)
    : data{static_cast<T>(values)...}
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(values) == N, "wrong size");
    }
    std::array<T,N> data;
};

int main()
{
    vector<int, 3> v = {1,2,3};
    vector<double, 4> vv = {5,4,3,2};

    vv = {1,2,3,4};

    //vector<float, 3> vf = {1,2,3,4}; // fails to compile
    vector<float,3> vf = v;
}
```

[Live example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/504427107b6d17fb).

It gets you a custom error message, easily adaptable/extensible condition for failure, and gets rid of the "narrowing conversion" problem by effectively forwarding the initialization to the `std::array` initializer like you wanted to do in the first place. Oh, and you get assignment for free.

As @M.M mentions, this solution ruins copy construction, unfortunately. You can solve it by adding an `enable_if` on the variadic arguments "array" size as shown above. Of course you need to be careful to not ruin assignment/copy-construction and single-element vectors, which is remedied by adding two extra constructors for these special cases.

Comment: Copy-construction doesn't seem to work with this solution, e.g. `vector<int, 3> w(v);`.

Comment: @M.M right, I figured that out (see edit) by looking at your answer :/. It seems there's no obvious/elegant/simplistic way out of that. It's either one or the other.... Wait, I can't seem to get the copy constructor selected over the variadic template (and I thought non-template functions were selected over template functions :o)... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc994313c1291e30

Comment: After template argument deduction we have as viable functions the non-template copy constructor `Vector(const Vector&)` and the variadic member template constructor `Vector(U&&)` but with `U` replaced by `Vector&` giving `Vector(Vector&)` by reference collapsing. Since `Vector(Vector&)` doesn't require low-level const conversion it is selected (non-template functions aren't selected if there is a template with a better match).

Comment: A solution would be to use `const U&` or `const U&&` or even just `U`, I don't think it's important to carry on the const or lvalue/rvalue property of my arguments. I guess by using `U&&` and preserving const and lvalue/rvalue properties you require no conversions and risk that function becoming a better match in overload resolution than the ordinary copy-control.

Comment: This needs an `enable_if`; as written it's too greedy. (It also creates an implicit conversion from everything.)

Comment: I'm forwarding greediness to the initialization of `std::array`, really, so "implicit conversion from everything" only works as long as the "everything" is compatible with the brace initialization of `std::array` and `T`. I think I fixed the shortcomings now, @M.M. Not sure if this solution is "neater" than yours. It does avoid the arg-expansion trick though.

Comment: It's still constructible from every combination of two or more arguments as far as `std::is_constructible` is concerned. The member initializer list doesn't SFINAE.

Comment: @T.C. That would be a failing in the trait, as it clearly isn't constructible from everything. I think this version satisfies all concerns the problem presents. If not, I'll be glad to think on concrete improvements!

Comment: @T.C. Something like `typename = typename enable_if<is_convertible<U, double>::value>::type...` along with `typename = typename enable_if<sizeof...(U) == N>::type` inside the template parameter list, but there seems to be a restriction on expanding packs declared in the same list ([14.1]/15 of N3337).

Comment: @AntiElephant That's not valid syntax. You want something along the lines of `typename = typename enable_if<std::conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<U, double>...>>::type` (`conjunction_v` is C++17 but readily implementable in C++14 (or C++11 with `::value` instead of `_v`)).

Answer (score 5):

This code seems to work, for both constructor and assignment-operator:

```
#include <array>

template<size_t N>
struct Vector
{
    Vector() = default;

    template<typename...Args>
    Vector(double d, Args... args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N-1, "wrong args count");

        size_t idx = 0;
        auto vhelp = [&](double d) { x[idx++] = d; };
        vhelp(d);
        double tmp[] { (vhelp(args), 1.0)... };
    }

    Vector &operator=(Vector const &other) = default;

private:
    std::array<double, N> x = {};
};

int main()
{
    Vector<5> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    v = { 3,4,5,6,7 };

    Vector<1> w = { 1,2 };  // error
}
```

The assignment operator works because the constructor is implicit, so `v = bla` attempts to convert `bla` to match the only definition of `operator=`.

I made the first argument `double d` instead of just using all variadic args, to avoid the issue where all-variadic-args constructor catches calls that were supposed to be copy-construction.

The line involving `double tmp[]` uses what I call the [variadic template comma operator hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620783/int-a-functioncalla1-a2-0-voida-what-does-this-syntax-do-mea/). This hack has many uses, but here it lets us avoid the narrowing-conversion issue that `double tmp[] { args... };` has.

(TBH though, incorporating rubvenvb's idea and using `double tmp[] { static_cast<double>(args)... };` would be simpler)

Comment: Nice solution. Although I'm not all too familiar with syntax when it comes to unpacking. It seems odd that just something like `vhelp(args)... ;` isn't also valid syntax and it is indeed necessary to create a temporary array (isn't unpacking just the same as writing `vhelp(a1), vhelp(a2), vhelp(a3), ...`?)

Comment: @AntiElephant unfortunately there is no syntax for directly calling a function once for each member of the pack; that's what's achieved by the comma operator hack.  I guess there would be a technical reason why they didn't make `f(args)...;` be possible

Comment: It can be done in certain contexts. Like passing the expansion to a function. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3288f60d506227f7

Comment: @AntiElephant looks like another hack..:)